# How to add compatibilty -C in bluez5.inc

Tags: bluetooth, sdp, imx6

Can I add 
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd **-C** 
compatibilty in **bluez5.inc**. If so, how we can add -C.

I am unable to get service details and /etc/systemd.../dbus.org.bluez.service is read only (It should be read only).
 **sdptool browse local**
**Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can create patch file. But I am trying to add compatibility in source file(bluez5.inc).